# How can I check user capability when a page loads (via functions.php)?

Tags: pages, hooks

I need to restrict users without a specific capability from seeing a specific page. I can't use shortcodes or anything like that, I just want to redirect them if they get to that page URL.

I want to do this by adding something to my functions.php file... I would imagine the code would be something like...

```
// hook on_page_load() into wordpress page load
function on_page_load($current_page_ID) {
    if( $current_page_ID == 1234 && is_user_logged_in() &&
        current_user_can('do_something_special')) {
           return;  // allow it to continue
    } else {
           // otherwise
           die();   // or redirect or whatever
    }
}
```

I can't quite figure out how to intercept each page load to see if they're going to the posts page. Can someone help? Or is there a more elegant way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect, a good event to use is `template_redirect`:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
function my_page_template_redirect() {
    // You can skip is_user_logged_in() if checking the user capability
    if( is_page( 1234 ) && ! current_user_can( 'do_something_special' ) ) {
        $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/redirection-page';
        // Default code status for redirection using wp_redirect is 302
        // If you need a different status code check
        // https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect
        wp_redirect( esc_url_raw( $redirect_to ) );
        exit();
    }

}
```

You can find more information about [`template_redirect` in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect).

As your question was about "how to intercept each page load", I think you should start reading these entries in the Codex:

1. [Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)
2. [Action definition](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Action) and [actions reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)
3. [Filter definition](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Filter) and [filters reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)

Basically, actions are events that occur while WordPress processes a request. Each of them is appropiate to "intercept" the request and do actions. As they occur in different moments, you can choose the best action to use depending on what you need to do.

In this case about redirection when some page is requested and the user has some capibility assigned, `template_redirect` could be a very appropiate moment to intercept the request. According with the documentation of this action: "It is a good hook to use if you need to do a redirect with full knowledge of the content that has been queried".

Comment: I think the OP wanted to redirect users without the special capability. It looks like non-logged-in users can now view page 1234.